# Why does my formula break when linked to an external workbook?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below working formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(C:C,MATCH("Heading 1",E:E,0)):INDEX(C:C,MATCH("Heading 2",E:E,0))="EUR")*(INDEX(V:V,MATCH("Heading 1",E:E,0)):INDEX(V:V,MATCH("Heading 2",E:E,0))<10)*INDEX(L:L,MATCH("Heading 1",E:E,0)):INDEX(L:L,MATCH("Heading 2",E:E,0))/INDEX(F:F,MATCH("Fund Valuation",E:E,0))*INDEX(V:V,MATCH("Heading 1",E:E,0)):INDEX(V:V,MATCH("Heading 2",E:E,0)))
```

When I apply this to a different workbook and then amend to add the full file pathway to each column array, the formula only works if the source file is open.  Once it is closed, a #REF! error is returned.

Note, when amending the formula to work on a different workbook I would use the full file pathway.  E.g:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX('C:\Reports\[Budget.xlsx]Annual'!C:C,MATCH("Heading 1",'C:\Reports\[Budget.xlsx]Annual'!E:E... etc
```

How can I get my formula to work when the source file is closed?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: link the file into another worksheet as a dynamic data source

Comment: Your approach of using full path is correct and it seems that even after including full paths your formula length may be less than 1500 characters which is much less than permissible limit of 8192 characters. Other reasons attributable are the differing format of some matching columns cells or values. In such a case you may try mock up of a simpler formula involving very few columns where you have confidence on data validity and try to run the formula to check whether it works on closed workbook. It is difficult to simulate lengthy formulas without a mock up sample data.